# jQuery animate duration not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, duration

By went through all similar questions here I have a question regarding to my code with jQuery animate duration failure. My purpose is to use ajax pull the long content from DB and fill the div, then expand the div to appropriate height. Please you are more than welcome to point out anything that isn't good enough in my theory. But when come back to the duration failure, it simply doesn't work and I cannot find why.

```
$('.button_expand_news').click(function() {
    $(this).text('LOADING...');
    var pod = $(this).prev();
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $.ajax({
        url: 'func.blogs.php?p=loadNews&id=' + id,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response) {
            var content = response['full_content'];
            pod.html('');
            pod.html(content);
            pod.animate({
                height: '100%'
            }, 500, function() {
                $(this).next().text('COLLAPSE');
            });
        }
    });
}
```

The demo page can be referred to [my project site](http://tiams.0zed.com/news.php).

Comment: You realize your test site has the animate duration set to 0 right?  http://tiams.0zed.com/lib/news.js

Comment: Yup Rick, it doesn't work even duration is set to 1000. So I set it to zero to save system resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's a guess :

have you set your "pod" div with height : 0 and overflow:hidden in your css ?

if yes, next guess

replace

```
 height: '100%'
```

with

```
 height:pod.parent().innerHeight()
```